# Unexpected behaviour with passthru in php

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx

I've set up nginx and php on an ubuntu server 12.04. I have the following php file:

```
<?php
echo "Hello ";
echo passthru("cat /proc/meminfo");
echo "world. I am ";
echo passthru("whoami");   
?>
```

This works completely fine when run from the command line, and php returns the text from /proc/meminfo. When run via nginx, however, I see this:

```
Hello world. I am www-data
```

Clearly, passthru is working. However, I can't seem to read anything in /proc. The permissions on /proc is dr-xr-xr-x, and I have confirmed that the www-data user that nginx and php run as can access that directory. I've turned on the php logging, and there are no error messages related to this.

Suggestions?

Edit: Safe mode is turned off.

Comment: have you got error logging/reporting enabled?

Comment: I do. But this isn't producing an error :( It's failing silently. I have confirmed that the error logging is working, though.

Comment: Is it perhaps running your stuff in a chrooted enviroment or something? That might explain why "whoami" works but not "cat /proc/meminfo".

Comment: hmmm, I'll have a look into that. A quick google doesn't seem to suggest that it's in any way a default setup, though :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, we fixed this offline -- I'm putting this up here for the next person who has this issue:

We verified that using the full path to cat resolved the problem.  There was no visible error because passthru doesn't capture stderr (and the error was a failure to find cat).  The River then discovered that $PATH was being set to the wrong thing, and fixed it.

Comment: The init script for the php5 daemon was explicitly setting the path (a good thing), but leaving off /bin, which is where cat lives.